# issue running spark-submit : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.couchbase.spark.streaming.Mutation.key()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-submit

I have the following scala code and am using sbt to compile and run this. **sbt run** works as expected.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{StreamingContext, Seconds}
import com.couchbase.spark.streaming._


object StreamingExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Create the Spark Config and instruct to use the travel-sample bucket
    // with no password.
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .setAppName("StreamingExample")
      .set("com.couchbase.bucket.travel-sample", "")

    // Initialize StreamingContext with a Batch interval of 5 seconds
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))

    // Consume the DCP Stream from the beginning and never stop.
    // This counts the messages per interval and prints their count.
    ssc
      .couchbaseStream(from = FromBeginning, to = ToInfinity)
        .foreachRDD(rdd => {
          rdd.foreach(message => {
            //println(message.getClass());
            message.getClass();
            if(message.isInstanceOf[Mutation]) {
              val document = message.asInstanceOf[Mutation].key.map(_.toChar).mkString
              println("mutated: " +  document);
            } else if( message.isInstanceOf[Deletion]) {
              val document = message.asInstanceOf[Deletion].key.map(_.toChar).mkString
              println("deleted: " + document);
            }
          })
        })

    // Start the Stream and await termination
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

but this fails when run as a spark job like below : 
    spark-submit --class "StreamingExample" --master "local[*]" target/scala-2.11/spark-samples_2.11-1.0.jar

The error is **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.couchbase.spark.streaming.Mutation.key()**

Following is my build.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "spark-samples",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("StreamingExample")        
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0",
  "com.couchbase.client" %% "spark-connector" % "2.2.0"
)

// META-INF discarding
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
       case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
       case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }
```

The spark version running on my machine is 2.4.0 using scala 2.11.12.

**Observations:**

I do not see **com.couchbase.client_spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0** in my spark jars ( /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.0/libexec/jars ), but the older version **com.couchbase.client_spark-connector_2.10-1.2.0.jar** exists.

- Why is spark-submit not working?
- how does sbt manage to run this? where does it download the
  dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that both the Scala version and the spark connector library version used by SBT and your spark installation are the same.

I had run into a similar problem when I was trying to run a sample Flink job on my system. It was being caused by version mismatch.

Comment: how do i check the spark connector library versions used by both SBT and spark installation are same ?